# foreach with key in dictionary

Tags: c#

How do I loop a dictionarys values that has a certain key?

```
foreach(somedictionary<"thiskey", x>...?
```

/M

Comment: A *dictionary* only **has** one value per key, so there is no need to foreach...

Comment: You may take a look at this answer [dictionary values in a foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070766/editing-dictionary-values-in-a-foreach-loop/1070795#1070795) in case you need to iterate over keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *dictionary* only **has** one value per key, so there is no need to foreach... you *might* just check whether it is there (`ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`):

```
SomeType value;
if(somedictionary.TryGetValue("thisKey", out value)) {
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

If `SomeType` is actually a list, then you could of course do:

```
List<SomeOtherType> list;
if(somedictionary.TryGetValue("thisKey", out list)) {
    foreach(value in list) {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

A *lookup* (`ILookup<TKey,TValue>`) has multiple values per key, and is just:

```
foreach(var value in somedictionary["thisKey"]) {
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is at most one value for a given key, so `foreach` serves no purpose. Perhaps you are thinking of some kind of multimap concept. I don't know if such a thing exists in the .Net class library.

Comment: multimap = `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`, most commonly the concrete `Lookup<TKey,TValue>` from `Enumerable.ToLookup`

Comment: Should I use linq on some list instead?

Comment: But the value could be a list.

Comment: @klausbyskov: Then you would simply be iterating over a list, and the fact that it came from a dictionary would be rather uninteresting.

Comment: True true true, but you never know with these questions.

Answer (score 3):

This extension method may be helpful for iterating through Dictionaries:

```
public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, Action<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> action) {
   foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item in source)
      action(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a dictionary declared like this: `var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`. You can loop through the values of a list for a given key like this:

```
foreach(var s in d["yourkey"])
    //Do something
```