# replace values of key value pair(A) with values of matching keys in key value pair(B)?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries(key value pair objects) in C#.  I want to compare dictionaries A with B and do the following **for any keys that are in both dictionaries**:
 1. Replace the value in dictionary A with the value in dictionary B
 2. Remove the matching key from dictionary B

An example would be as follows:

Initial dictionaries:

```
A={" Key1:value1 "," Key2:value2 "}
B={" Key3:bla "," key1:hello "," Key4:bla "," Key2:world "}
```

Afterward:

```
A={" Key1:hello "," Key2:world "}
B={" Key3:bla "," Key4:bla "}
```

I would like to know the best way to do this, I'm sure this can be achieved in LINQ but I am still just a beginner, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where Ani's answer went, but here's a similar solution:

```
foreach (var k in A.Keys.ToList())
{
    if (B.ContainsKey(k))
    {
        A[k] = B[k];
        B.Remove(k);
    }
}
```

**edit** it looks like the original code throws an `InvalidOperationException` when going through the `foreach` loop, thinking that the collection is modified. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070766/editing-dictionary-values-in-a-foreach-loop) for details.  `ToList()` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that is just slightly more compact:

```
    var keys = dictionaryA.Keys.Where(x => dictionaryB.Keys.Contains(x)).ToArray();
    foreach(var key in keys)
    {
         dictionaryA[key] = dictionaryB[key];
         dictionaryB.Remove(key);
    }
```