# using a for loop to iterate through a dictionary

Tags: c#, for-loop, dictionary

I generally use a foreach loop to iterate through Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictSummary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

In this case I want to trim the entries of white space and the foreach loop does however not allow for this.

```
foreach (var kvp in dictSummary)
{
    kvp.Value = kvp.Value.Trim();    
}
```

How can I do this with a for loop?

```
for (int i = dictSummary.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: or this ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070766/editing-dictionary-values-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @Belial09 In the question asked in the link you posted, it doesn't seem the keys are modified; just the values.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` doesn't allow you to set the `Value`, it is immutable.

You will have to do it like this:

```
foreach(var kvp in dictSummary.ToArray())
    dictSummary[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.Trim();
```

The important part here is the `ToArray`. That will copy the Dictionary into an array, so changing the dictionary inside the foreach will not throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

An alternative approach would use LINQ's `ToDictionary` method:

```
dictSummary = dictSummary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Trim());
```

Answer (score 65):

what about this?

```
for (int i = dictSummary.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var item = dictSummary.ElementAt(i);
  var itemKey = item.Key;
  var itemValue = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: While it is possible to use such code I'd not recommend it. `Enumerable.ElementAt` is not really best way to access elements in a dictionary... Your code is likely O(n^2) since Dictionary does not allow access to elements by position.

Comment: Why are you iterating from the end to the beginning? Don't tell me, it's because of performance reasons...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ...Thanks. I didn't know about this. just searched the issue and it looks like a huge drawback. Thanks again.

Comment: @DHN...well, i've just copied it from the ques

Comment: This isn't a good use case of reverse iteration.  But the proper use case is if you plan to remove items.  That way a removal doesn't affect your iteration/count.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use `.ToArray()` or `.ElementAt()`. It is as simple as accessing the dictionary with the key:

```
dictSummary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k => dictSummary[k] = dictSummary[k].Trim());
```